# Finding out MapInfo file projection

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, mapinfo

I need to process some MapInfo data in QGIS 3.4, but I am unfamiliar with MapInfo. The data seems wrong when compared to a Google Satellite base map. I do not know the projection of the MapInfo layer, and this is the GDAL-Vector information output:

```
INFO: Open of 'C:/.../LAYER.MIF'
      using driver 'MapInfo File' successful.

Layer name: LAYER
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 9
Extent: (12.291721, 41.737178) - (12.641386, 42.011683)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["unnamed",
    DATUM["Arc 1950",
        ELLIPSOID["Clarke 1880 (modified for Arc 1950)",6378249.145326,293.4663076,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Name: String (50.0)
```

I have tried reprojecting the layer to the two projections mentioned (EPSG:9001 and EPSG:9122), but the data remains wrong. In an associated .WOR file, I found this command:

```
Set Map
  CoordSys Earth Projection 1, 5
  Center (12.35610885,41.95712217)
  Zoom 60.26835134 Units "mi"
  Preserve Zoom Display Zoom
  XY Units "m" Distance Units "mi" Area Units "sq mi"
```

I do not know whether this is relevant, and couldn't find the exact meaning of Earth Projection 1, 5 on MapInfo documentation. Is there a way to know this layer's projection?

Comment: According to http://read.pudn.com/downloads138/sourcecode/others/592839/Mapinfo_Mif.pdf

CoordSys Earth Projection 1, 5 is Latlong, Datum Arc1950

Comment: [EPSG](https://www.epsg.org) says that Arc 1950 is used in "Africa - Botswana, Malawi, Zambia, Zimbabwe" but the data extent doesn't seem to match that.

Comment: The valid datum for Ethiopia is Adindan, this also uses the Clarke1880 ellipsoid, just as Arc1950

Comment: @HansErren thank you for the pdf link, that's very useful.

Comment: As the mif file is ascii, the line 'CoordSys Earth Projection 1, 5' can be edited to'CoordSys Earth Projection 1, 1' to match the Adindan datum in Ethiopia with EPSG code 4201.

Comment: Is the data supposed to be near Djibouti, or Rome?

Comment: @CL. near Rome, the extent is written as (lon, lat)

Comment: All lat/lon projections are quite similar; if this particular ellipsoid is not correct, it will be almost impossible to find the correct one. I suspect the data is mislabeled and actually in WGS84. Try changing to `Projection 1, 104` without reprojection.

Comment: If the data is near Rome then your lat and long are swapped, the clarke ellipsoid is often picked as default in older datasets. picking the wrong datum/ellipsoid gives location errors in the order of 500 m. So I suggest to start with swapping your lat and longs and then report what you location error is. The default (and most likely) datum for Italy is Monte Mario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MapInfo projection database, `1, 5` is called "Longitude / Latitude (Arc 1950)" and has the EPSG ID 4209.

Comment: Thank you. Unluckily this is bad news, because this projection doesn't make sense considering the data extent, and reprojecting does not make the data look any better. This is the answer I was looking for anyway.

Comment: Can you post the first twenty lines of the file Layer.mif, and do you have an idea where the data should be located, then I might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on MapInfo's projection strings can be found in a MapInfo Pro User Guide, e.g. [https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/mapinfo-pro/v2021/en-us/pdf/mapinfo-pro-v2021-user-guide.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20230328085922/https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/mapinfo-pro/v2021/en-us/pdf/mapinfo-pro-v2021-user-guide.pdf) under "Building Blocks of a Coordinate System" (page 825 in the linked file).

In this case, the `1` is the projection type, found in the "Projection Types List" (p. 836) as "Longitude/Latitude" and the `5` is the projection datum, listed under "Projection Datums" (p. 840) with Datum Name: "Arc 1950" and Ellipsoid: "Clarke 1880".

If you have MapInfo, you can find a MapInfo coordinate system's internal name and corresponding EPSG code (if it exists) in the `MAPINFOW.PRJ` file in the install directory. EPSG codes in the file are preceded by `\p`. (Here's an online version of the file that may be out of date: [https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vT568ND7ZOtuqjNsxs-u7wgFJrNgTpdX99voLJAm_4TAcRhu6dI8wOuSQazBtZvwoV77B-WJJWYDinP/pub](https://web.archive.org/web/20230831020602/https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vT568ND7ZOtuqjNsxs-u7wgFJrNgTpdX99voLJAm_4TAcRhu6dI8wOuSQazBtZvwoV77B-WJJWYDinP/pub))

In this case, the projection is `"Longitude / Latitude (Arc 1950)\p4209", 1, 5` - its code is EPSG:4209.